# Bootsrap last carousel image transition glitch

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm currently working on a portfolio website for myself. I'm implementing a Carousel based on Bootstrap's example. However, the transitions between the first or second slides into the third one are kind of glitched, and the picture overlaps with the next or previous one. This is mostly visible when in the mobile version of the website by the way.

Here's the website: https://esteban-jimenez.com/ so you guys can see what I'm referring to.

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Here's are the sections that are giving me trouble:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <!-- <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg> -->
            <img class="image-1" src="images/main-jumbotron-small.png" alt="Main Carousel">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-start">
                <h1>Hi, I'm Esteban</h1>
                <p>Engineer, leader and innovator. Click here to know more about me!</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="about.html">About Me</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="image-2" src="images/carousel2.jpg"  class="cover" alt="Carousel 2">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Deep Learning and Cancer</h1>
                <p>One of my current research projects. Check it out!</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="image-3" src="images/carousel3.jpg"  class="cover" alt="Carousel 3">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-end">
                <h1>Want to know more about my work?</h1>
                <p>Go ahead and click here to check my experience.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">My Experience</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

As I said, the only carousel slide where I'm facing this issue is with the last one (the last .carousel-item). I haven't really modified the CSS that comes with the bootstrap files regarding the carousel except for the opacity of the pictures in the slides.

Comment: Could you share code from the code section that is failing you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change min-width to width and it should fix the issue:

```css
.carousel-item > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just vitisted your site, after checking it on console its says :

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR ...images/main-jumbotron-small.png
```

Try this :

```
<img class="image-1" src="/images/main-jumbotron-small.png" alt="Main Carousel">
```

add '`/`' to all your image link that is : `/images/main-jumbotron-small.png`.

Comment: Is it okay to use two dots before the first slash? As in: ../images

Comment: Dots here means parent folder so two dots i.e two folder above the image located.